# Can't "activate" virtualenv

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv, python-venv

New to running Python in virtual environments, messing with Django, and can't activate a virtual environment.

Spent the last 4 hrs trying to activate a virtual env (venv) on local terminal/VS Code with no luck.

Avoided "sudo pip install virtualenv" as I was trying to avoid installing as root and having different directory path, etc.

### "pip install virtualenv" output:

Collecting virtualenv
Using cached virtualenv-20.0.31-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.9 MB)

Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in /Users/garrettpinto/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.15.0)

Requirement already satisfied: appdirs<2,>=1.4.3 in /Users/garrettpinto/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.4.4)

Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in /Users/garrettpinto/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.0.12)

Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.1 in /Users/garrettpinto/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.1)

Installing collected packages: virtualenv

Successfully installed virtualenv-20.0.31

### "virtualenv venv" output:

created virtual environment CPython3.8.5.final.0-64 in 416ms

creator CPython3Posix(dest=/Users/garrettpinto/Desktop/rp-portfolio/distribution/venv, clear=False, global=False)

seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/garrettpinto/Library/Application Support/virtualenv)

added seed packages: pip==20.2.2, setuptools==49.6.0, wheel==0.35.1

activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator

### "source venv/bin/activate" returns nothing

### "./venv/bin/activate" output:

zsh: permission denied: ./venv/bin/activate

### "sudo ./venv/bin/activate" output:

sudo: ./venv/bin/activate: command not found

Thoughts?

Comment: Delete the venv, make sure permissions where you're running/installing are correct so that you don't need sudo & try again.

Comment: @markwalker_ I used "chmod -R 0777" for the venv directory and still "source venv/bin/activate" doesn't work

Comment: For me its similiar, I tried with zsh and with bash under Ubuntu 20.04, but the venv does not activate, I can see that which python does not change...

Comment: @garp instead of "./venv/bin/activate" , just do ". venv/bin/activate". There is a space between the "." and "venv". Hope it helps.

Answer (score 13):

There's a lot of confusing information out there on virtual environments, because of how they have evolved. Since Python 3.3, the `venv` module is available with Python as part of the standard library to create virtual environments, and if you're just getting started, I'd recommend learning it first. There's nothing extra to install after you've installed Python 3.8.

From your project's home directory in the VSCode terminal, try this:

```
python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install Django
```

Here's what the three lines do:

1. Call the Python module `venv` and create a new virtual environment in the directory `venv`
2. Run the script to activate the virtual environment that is located in the path `venv/bin/activate`
3. Now that the `venv` is activated, install Django.

After the first time install, you'll just need to repeat step (2) to activate it. You can also point VSCode to automatically start it when you fire up the IDE. You can click the bar at the bottom of VSCode after installing the Python plugin to select the Python version in the `venv` you've created. Good luck!

**Update:**

Here's an example of it working in `zsh` on my machine:

```
$ zsh
% python3 --version
Python 3.8.2
% python3 -m venv venv
% . venv/bin/activate
(venv) % pip install Django
Collecting Django
Collecting pytz (from Django)
Collecting asgiref~=3.2.10 (from Django)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2 (from Django)
Installing collected packages: pytz, asgiref, sqlparse, Django
Successfully installed Django-3.1.1 asgiref-3.2.10 pytz-2020.1 sqlparse-0.3.1
```

Comment: So even with using "python3 -m venv venv" 


the ". venv/bin/activate" did not activate a virtual environment

Comment: Is it not working because I'm using zsh instead of bash?

The first two lines of the "activate" file read: 
# This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*
# you cannot run it directly

Comment: I've updated my answer showing that it works for `zsh` on my machine. Are you running MacOS, Ubuntu, or something else?

Comment: For Debian 11 the first time I created a venv, everything seemed to work until activation. "command not found". After deleting and trying again, I got a message:     "The virtual environment was not created successfully because ensurepip is not
available.  On Debian/Ubuntu systems, you need to install the python3-venv
package using the following command.

    apt-get install python3-venv" HTH

Comment: This worked for me, the thing that was not working was that missing period `.` at the beginning of the activate script run line: `. venv/Scripts/activate`, this period was missing in official Python tutorial: [12. Virtual Environments and Packages — Python 3.12.1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html), also one must note that the script are different for different shells, as noted in the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

I was stuck on this for a good while
but you can try venv:

```
python -m venv virtualenvname

#to activate the virtual environment

source virtualenvname/Scripts/activate
```

Comment: It is for Windows. `activate` script for `Windows` is located at `venv\Scripts\activate`, for `Unix` systems it is at `venv/bin/activate`

Answer (score 1):

```
Solution of the problem of virtual environment created but not activated.

to make activate just add a space between .(dot) and your venv path. i,e 
$ . yourvirtualenv/bin/activate
Hope this will work. But not use like:
$ yourvirtualenv/bin/activate
or
$ /yourvirtualenv/bin/activate

Here is my command and the output:

admin@osboxes:~/pysrc$ . my_env/bin/activate
(my_env) admin@osboxes:~/pysrc$ 

Output of the wrong command:

admin@osboxes:~/pysrc$ my_env/bin/activate
bash: my_env/bin/activate: Permission denied
admin@osboxes:~/pysrc$ sudo my_env/bin/activate
[sudo] password for admin: 
sudo: my_env/bin/activate: command not found
admin@osboxes:~/pysrc$ my_env/bin/activate
bash: my_env/bin/activate: Permission denied
admin@osboxes:~/pysrc$
```

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to your `venv` folder. You will find `pyvenv.cfg`

With

```
sudo change set parameter "include-system-site-package" = "true"
```

and then execute your

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 0):

I just prefer using 'venv' as a name for all my virtual environments, so always I'll use the same command to activate environments in my machine.

Try:

```
# Create the virtual environment inside your project's folder
$ python3 -m venv venv

#Activate it
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

As I need to change projects and environments quite often, I created two alias in the system (ubuntu 20.04), one for creating and another to activate it, as shown above:

To create I chose 'venv' as my alias name. Before creating I certified that an existing 'venv' folder was deleted.

```
venv='rm -rf venv && python3.9 -m venv venv'
```

To activate I chose 'activate' as my alias name

```
activate='source venv/bin/activate'
```

Window commands to create and activate are a little different as you can notice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66432333/11755155).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It came right out of nowhere. To keep it simple please use **source** for running the activate script. In Linux e.g.

```
source .virtualenvs/test/bin/activate
```

I don't know why but these became crucial.

Code up Donald

Answer (score 0):

this works for me
`cd`  to your folder with `.bin` folder
activate -  `. bin/activate`

Comment: This solution is already provided in another answer. If you have any different solution please mention it. If there is any change/extension required to the original answer, then edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Before activating the virtual environment, run this command on terminal `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process`, and then activate the virtual environment.

Comment: This question was on macOS, you shouldn't answer with Windows NT examples.